# Sharding to multiple databases with angularfire2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, sharding

I'm trying desperately to setup Firebase database sharding into an Ionic v3 (Angular 4) app in order to decrease the Realtime Database load values.

I almost made it work, except one small detail.

So what I've done is the following:

- initialized a new app

  `const app2 = firebase.initializeApp({ databaseURL: "https://app2.firebaseio.com/" },  "app2");`
- then in a service I'm using AngularFireDatabase:

  `constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}`
- then when I want to simply get a list of items from the second database I do

  `this.afDatabase.list(firebase.database(app2).ref('/items'));`

  which works just fine.

But the problem now is that when I pass in a query object, like this

```
this.afDatabase.list(firebase.database(app2).ref('/items'), {
    query: {
          orderByChild: "item_id",
          equalTo: 5
     }
});
```

this query is completely ignored, it actually returns the whole list under /items.

Comment: Related [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md). Related github threads [1](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1567) [2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1026). Offer some clues but no clear resolution. Note that nothing in the doc suggests this method of constructing a list is valid.

Comment: I agree @Kato, it's a workaround. And I would be happy to find any other workaround just to make angularfire2 work with multiple firebase databases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a bug is in `list()` and `object()` methods implementation in `database.ts` file under angularfire2 package, version 2.0.0-beta.8

More exactly, this line

```
isRef: () => FirebaseObjectFactory(urlOrRef)
```

should actually be

```
isRef: () => FirebaseObjectFactory(urlOrRef, opts)
```

both under `list()` and `object()` functions.

With this fix, and a rebuild of angularfire2 package, I managed to made it work.